# L^1 maximal inequalities for the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck semigroup in infinite dimension

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, gaussian

For an infinite-dimensional Gaussian random vector $X$ consider the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck maximal operator:

$M f(X) := \sup_{\rho \in [0,1]} \mathsf{E} [f(\rho X + (1-\rho^2)^{1/2} X^\prime) \mid X]$

(defined using an appropriate separable version in $\rho$), where $X^\prime$ is an independent copy.

As far as I know, the question whether $M$ is of weak type $(1,1)$ in infinite dimensions was open at least a couple of decades ago.

So is it still open? Is it true at least that $M f < +\infty$ almost everywhere for $f \in L^1$?